# perl idiom for substituting in a line range (sed-like)

Tags: perl, sed

One of the nice features of `sed` is that commands (among them substitutions) can be restricted to a range of lines defined by regexp expressions (or by line number, but never mind that). Here's a simple example:

```
sed '/^Page 5:/,/^Page 6:/s/this/that/g'
```

I was just trying to convert a rather more complex sed script to perl, and while the regexp substitutions are no problem, I realized that I don't know a straightforward way to limit substitutions to a range of lines. I can write

```
perl -p -e 's/^(Page 5:.*)this/$1that/g'
```

to change `this` to `that` on lines starting with `Page 5:`, but not on the lines that follow (and even on this line, despite the `g` it's only going to substitute once since matches are non-overlapping). Short of writing an explicit input loop and keeping track in a state variable like `$inrange`, isn't there a nice shortcut that can do this? This being perl, surely there must be!

Comment: `perl -pe's/this/that/g if /^Page 5:/../^Page 6:/'`

Comment: Exactly! Thanks. After reading @Sobrique's answer I came up with the one-liner syntax as well.

Comment: PS. I'm surprised this question is (apparently) not a duplicate!

Comment: And you can even use line numbers as well (like in sed): `perl -pe 's/this/that/g if 1../^Page 6:/' that would be from first line to the one matching Page 6. Note that perl's line index starts at 1 instead of 0 compared to sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is. What you have in perl is the ['range operator'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

It goes a bit like this:

```
if ( m/Page 5:/ .. m/Page 6:/ ) { 
     s/this/that/g;
}
```

This will evaluate as 'true' if you're between the two patterns, and false otherwise.

E.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


while (<DATA>) {
    if ( m/Page 5:/ .. m/Page 6:/ ) {
        s/this/that/g;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__

Page 1:
this
this
more this
Page 5:
this 
this this
this
Page 6:
this 
more this
and some more this
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that's a pretty direct translation for the simple case, which is all I need. And I can use it in one-liners with `-e 's/this/that/g if (m/A/..m/B/);`